# implement PCA in python and k nearest

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

i want to implement Dimensionality Reduction with Neighborhood Components Analysis in classification using k Nearest neighbourhood
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_nca_dim_reduction.html
but i got error, how can i fix this?
the X_train value has string on it, how to convert to float?
do i have to fit and transform manually?
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '分散 システム : 原理 と パラダイム'

code [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sSlc5rEIIuyWc3R11nZ_-vwlTimBKhJj#scrollTo=Hd2BFDekWcq3&line=159&uniqifier=1)

```
!wget http://www.cs.gunma-u.ac.jp/~michi/toku2/book_category.tgz
!tar zxf book_category.tgz


topics = [
'computer_graphics',
'operating_systems',
'computer_security',
'application_service',
'computer_software',
'artificial_intelligence',
'search_engine',
'information_society',
]

import glob
import re

import MeCab
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

docs = []
for topic in topics:
    for f in glob.glob(f"./book_category/{topic}/*.txt"):

        with open(f, "r") as fin:
            body = "\n".join([line.strip() for line in fin if line.strip()])
        docs.append((topic,body))

df = pd.DataFrame(
        docs,
        columns=["topic","body"],
        dtype="category"
)



df.head()


df.topic.value_counts()



tagger = MeCab.Tagger("-Owakati")

def parse_to_wakati(text):
    return tagger.parse(text).strip()

df = df.assign(body_wakati=df.body.apply(parse_to_wakati))


le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(df.topic)

print(le.classes_)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
                                      df.body_wakati,  #input
                                      y, #right label
                                      test_size=0.2, 
                                      random_state=10,
                                      shuffle=True
)

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
class RulebasedEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, label_encoder):
        self.le = label_encoder

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        """ルールを記述"""
        result = []
        for text in X:
            pred = 0
            if re.search(r"(コンピュータ|グラフィックス)", text):
                pred = self.le.transform(["computer_graphics"])[0]
            elif re.search(r"(オペレーティング|システム)", text):
                pred = self.le.transform(["operating_systems"])[0]
            elif re.search(r"(暗号|セキュリティ)", text):
                pred = self.le.transform(["computer_security"])[0]
            elif re.search(r"(アプリケーション|サービス)", text):
                pred = self.le.transform(["application_service"])[0]
            elif re.search(r"(コンピュータ|ソフトウェア)", text):
                pred = self.le.transform(["computer_software"])[0]
            elif re.search(r"(人工|知能)", text):
                pred = self.le.transform(["artificial_intelligence"])[0]
            elif re.search(r"(検索|エンジン)", text):
                pred = self.le.transform(["search_engine"])[0]
            elif re.search(r"(情報|社会)", text):
                pred = self.le.transform(["information_society"])[0]
            result.append(pred)
        return result

rulebased = RulebasedEstimator(label_encoder=le)

rulebased_pred = rulebased.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_test,rulebased_pred)


print(classification_report(y_test, rulebased_pred, target_names=le.classes_))


#Import knearest neighbors Classifier model
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import (NeighborhoodComponentsAnalysis,KNeighborsClassifier)
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
random_state = 0
nca = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),NeighborhoodComponentsAnalysis(n_components=2,random_state=random_state))

neigh=30
print("KNN_neighbour="+str(neigh)+"\n")
pca = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),PCA(n_components=2, random_state=random_state))

# Reduce dimension to 2 with PCA
pca = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    PCA(n_components=2, random_state=random_state))

# Reduce dimension to 2 with LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
lda = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2))

knn = Pipeline([
    ("tfidf", TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('nca',nca),
    ("clf",  KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=30,algorithm='kd_tree')),
])
#Train the model using the training sets
pca.fit(X_train, y_train)

knn.fit(model.transform(X_train), y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)

error = []


# Calculating error for K values between 1 and 10
for i in range(1,40):
    knn = Pipeline([
    ("tfidf", TfidfVectorizer()),
    ("clf",  KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)),
    ])
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    pred_i = knn.predict(X_test)
    error.append(np.mean(pred_i != y_test))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(range(1, 40), error, color='red', linestyle='dashed', marker='o',
         markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=10)
plt.title('Error Rate K Value')
plt.xlabel('K Value')
plt.ylabel('Mean Error')
```

i got this value error

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
    145 ])
    146 #Train the model using the training sets
--> 147 pca.fit(X_train, y_train)
    148 
    149 knn.fit(model.transform(X_train), y_train)

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '分散 システム : 原理 と パラダイム'

edit:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
print(X_train_tf)
print(X_train_tf.shape)



################################
change the pipeline for PCA


pca = Pipeline([
    ("tfidf", TfidfVectorizer()),
    ("clf",  PCA(n_components=2, random_state=random_state)),
])

#Train the model using the training sets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
# Fit on training set only.
scaler.fit(X_train) #i got error X_train is string not float
pca.fit(X_train_tf)
X_train=pca.transform(X_train_tf)

knn.fit(pca.transform(X_train_tf),y_train)
```

Comment: sklearn has an extensive section in the documentation on [working with text data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html). This question is far too broad for this site, but if you go through those docs and have a specific issue with a [mcve] then that would be more on-topic

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks but what do you mean by too broad? i just want to know how can i convert string to  float when training data is string , how can i get the tf-idf without using pipeline

Comment: Apologies, your question was unclear. You've built in the vectorizer in your knn pipeline, but the error is in your PCA pipeline, where you don't appear to have included any text handling at all. If you do the same in the PCA pipeline, you shouldn;t have a problem

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks but is it suppose to be like this? pca = Pipeline([StandardScaler(),("tfidf", TfidfVectorizer()),("clf",  PCA(n_components=2, random_state=random_state))])

Comment: In what you posted, the tf-idf comes after the standardscaler. But if the scaler is first, how could the pipeline find the standard deviation of `'分散 システム : 原理 と パラダイム'`? Good rule of thumb is to make adjustments to the text itself, then transform all text features to numeric, then anything else to the data that requires it to be numeric data

Comment: @G.Anderson so the X_train before the scaler has to be tf-idf? because i use pipeline, i dont count the tf-idf manual.  i try to get the tf-idf data itself in X_train_tf(see my edit), so the new x_train wil be  X_train_tf? or matrix form? i was confused what is the shape of X_train_tf

Comment: Whether in a pipeline or outside a pipeline, the text data must be transformed to tf-idf BEFORE applying numeric methods to it. In your edit, you're still trying to use a scaler on text data, which will not work. Note, you can also only use the scaler on the non-text columns if you have them, using `select_dtypes`, but if you want to scale data, it has to already be transformed to numeric

Comment: @G.Anderson Thankyou but how can i convert the x_train to numeric?  and also is the numeric data for this should be the tf-idf value? the x_train data consist of topic(book category) and the name of the books, if i need to change to numeric how can i change the name of the book? is it like this   <code> count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts) </code>

Comment: Yes, like that. Either tfidf or countvectorizer should work fine for making the text data numeric. Even OneHot encoder, if it's a limited set of text data like book category with repeated values. Just so long as you apply it before you try to do anything else with it.

Comment: @G.Anderson thankyou but when i want to get the tf-idf for test data, is the code like this 
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_test)
X_testt = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_testt = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)? in test data , it is said just need only transform ? i got error : Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 1692 and input n_features is 1693 .